# How to use OR operator in LINQ WHERE statement

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql

I just need an equivalent of this TSQL statement written in LINQ. Preferably in lambda statement but anything will work.
TSQL statement:

```
select *
from Table1 as t1
where t1.Column1 = a OR t1.Column2 = b
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just like other C# code use `||` for `OR`

Method Syntax:

```
var query = db.Table1
              .Where(r=> r.Column1 == a || r.Column2 == b);
```

Query Syntax:

```
var query = from r in db.Table1
            where r.Column1 == a || r.Column2 == b
            select r;
```

Query Syntax compiles into Method syntax.

See: [Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb397947.aspx)

> Most queries in the introductory Language Integrated Query (LINQ)
>   documentation are written by using the LINQ declarative query syntax.
>   However, the query syntax must be translated into method calls for the
>   .NET common language runtime (CLR) when the code is compiled.

You should see: [Basic LINQ Query Operations (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx)

Comment: @DStanley, I agree the wording is wrong, What I wanted to say is that query syntax compiles into method syntax and they are same in that sense ,

Comment: That I agree with.  I have deleted my comment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me.

IQueryable noveltydata = (IQueryable)noveltyOfPeriod;

var fillNoveltyData = noveltydata. Where(c => c.TypeDay != 2 || c.TypeDay == 8).
Where(c => c.EmployeeID == employeeID);

int DayNoSalary = (int)(from dataQueryVal in fillNoveltyData select dataQueryVal).Sum(e => e.Days);