# ASP.NET IQueryable WHERE OR

Tags: asp.net, iqueryable

I am trying to write this piece of code that will search the database table and I am trying to search multiple columns. What I have below appears to be the equivalent to WHERE column = "this" AND column2 = "this", what I am trying to do is this WHERE column = "this" OR column2 = "this" How would I accomplish this?

```
query = query.Where(p => (p.ChckNumber.ToString()).Contains(globalSearch.ToString()));
                    query = query.Where(p => (p.BankAccount.ToString()).Contains(globalSearch.ToString()));
                    query = query.Where(p => (p.Description.ToString()).Contains(globalSearch.ToString()));
                    query = query.Where(p => (p.CheckAmount.ToString()).Contains(globalSearch.ToString()));
                    query = query.Where(p => (p.ClearedDate.ToString()).Contains(globalSearch.ToString()));
                    query = query.Where(p => (p.SentDate.ToString()).Contains(globalSearch.ToString()));
```

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427485/how-to-use-or-operator-in-linq-where-statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use OR operator in LINQ WHERE statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427485/how-to-use-or-operator-in-linq-where-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this in-line using the `OR` operator:

```
query = query.Where(p => 
    p.ChckNumber.ToString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) ||
    p.BankAccount.ToString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) ||
    p.Description.ToString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) ||
    p.CheckAmount.ToString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) ||
    p.ClearedDate.ToString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) ||
    p.SentDate.ToString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString())
);
```

Comment: You have an extra ) after ToString()

Comment: Thanks! It's fixed.